# Does flutter(Dart) have a function similar to js bind?

Tags: javascript, dart, flutter

Does flutter(Dart) have a function similar to js bind?
I wanted to do something similar in flutter.

like:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title></title>
<script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
function handlerName(e) 
{
 alert(e.data.msg);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("p").bind("click", {msg: "chicked!"}, handlerName)
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>click me！</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm guessing this refers to `bind` from [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing like `bind` in Dart

but this might do what you want as well:

```
onReady.listen((e) => handlerName(e, msg: 'clicked'))
```

Comment: (As a pet peeve, I'll recommend using `forEach` instead of `listen` for uses like this).

Comment: Sorry. I was thinking of you when I posted but was afraid that might distract from the main point and confuse more than it helps. I'll be more consequent in the future :D